# C# compiler error in Visual Studio 2012, no longer error in VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is more of a curiosity question, since the fix is both easy and obvious.  I use Visual Studio 2015 but my team mate uses Visual Studio 2012.  We work on the same project.  Yea yea, this is a bad idea but we'll fix this soon hopefully.  Yesterday, I checked in some code which he integrated into his branch and immediately had compile errors.  Here's the code (it has been simplified a bit since not all of it is necessary):

```
//Load basic project information from db
var projInfo = (from v in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                join p in context.TPM_PROJECT on v.PROJECTID equals p.PROJECTID

                join pto in context.TPM_USER on v.TPM_USER1.USERID equals pto.USERID into primaryowner
                from subpto in primaryowner.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join pt in context.TPM_PROJECTTYPES on p.PROJECTTYPEID equals pt.PROJECTTYPEID
                where v.PROJECTID == projectId && v.VERSIONID == versionId
                select new
                {
                   ProjectName = v.NAME,
                   BusinessLaunchDate = p.BUSINESSLAUNCHDATE,
                   LearningExperiences = v.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONGAMEPLANS
                     .SelectMany(p => p.TPM_LEARNINGEXPERIENCES.Select(le => le.NAME)),
                }).First();
```

On my machine, this compiles and works fine.  On his machine, he gets the error:

> > Error 10 A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

The variable `p` in question is the `p` within the `.SelectMany` call:

`.SelectMany(p => p.TPM_LEARNINGEXPERIENCES.Select(le => le.NAME)),`

This apparently conflicts with the `p` defined in the above join:

`join p in context.TPM_PROJECT on v.PROJECTID equals p.PROJECTID`

To me, this seems fine.  So I hide a variable in an outer scope I no longer need.  I can fix his compile error by renaming one of the `p` variables.

**My Question:**

I know VS2012 uses C# 5.0, while VS2015 uses C# 6.0.  Did 6.0 get more *lenient* on variable names in an inner scope, or is there some other setting that's coming into play here.  Why is this an error on one and perfectly fine on another?  BTW, I don't get any warnings either so it's not a *Treat warnings as errors* type of thing either.

Ideas?

Comment: The more relevant issue here is that Roslyn happened in VS2015.  They *did* use the opportunity to fix many existing bugs and quirks in the C# compiler, better-now-or-never style.  And added thousands more but that's being worked on.  Nothing you can do but double-check with an old compiler.

Comment: @HansPassant - Ok so short answer is it may or may not have been a bug in the older compiler, or some behavior someone just felt like changing..  Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

AS a quick and save solution to avoid strange errors, Unify the building using c# 6 in both environment.
You can install c# 6.0 into VS2012 on a per project basis as a NuGet package

Installing C# Compiler via Nuget

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

Try this in a test environment and check if this error disappear.